# HTML5 Web Workers in NodeJS?

Tags: html, node.js, web-worker

Anyone knows what the status of Web Worker support in NodeJS is? I found a two year old implementation, node-webworkers, but it didn't run with the current build of NodeJS.

Answer (score 8):

Now there is https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads which appears to be actively maintained.

Comment: This looks like a really good way to abstract away a lot of the complexity of child_process.  In my experience there are a ton of gotchas in there, and using something to manage that seems like a good idea

Answer (score 5):

[Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/worker_threads.html) reached stable status in 12 LTS. Usage example

> ```
> const {
>   Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData
> } = require('worker_threads');
>
> if (isMainThread) {
>   module.exports = function parseJSAsync(script) {
>     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>       const worker = new Worker(__filename, {
>         workerData: script
>       });
>       worker.on('message', resolve);
>       worker.on('error', reject);
>       worker.on('exit', (code) => {
>         if (code !== 0)
>           reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
>       });
>     });
>   };
> } else {
>   const { parse } = require('some-js-parsing-library');
>   const script = workerData;
>   parentPort.postMessage(parse(script));
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [child processes](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), they solve similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the specifics of the HTML5 WebWorker source.

With a little care, you can 'redress' the WebWorker to fit as a Node.js worker, by adding a prelude that may look something like this:

```js
const { parentPort } = require('worker_threads')

global.postMessage = function(msg){
    parentPort.postMessage(msg)
}

var handler

global.addEventListener = function(kind, callback){
    handler = callback    
}

parentPort.on('message', msg => {
    handler(msg)
})
```

The specific HTML5 worker added a `message` event handler using `addEventListener`, so I registered such a function in `global` and saved the handler. I also had to supply a `postMessage` implementation. Finally I registered a Node.js message handler that invokes the HTML5 handler.

Everything works perfectly. No need for any special dependency, just looking at the HTML5 worker code and identify the points where it deals with messages.